# git push origin --delete [branching-and-merging]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

This tag [branching-and-merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branching-and-merging) combines both [git-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-branch) and [git-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge) (or, more generally [branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branch) and [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge)). I think it's redundant having it, and I can't think of a scenario where this tag must be used instead of combining the other two.

I thought about making it a synonym of one of [branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branch) or [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge), but it's not possible as one part will be missing (it's both branch and merge, and not only one of them).

Can we delete it? Or am I missing something important here?

Comment: A cursory glance at the first page shows questions related to other version control systems like svn and tfs

Comment: @SurajRao True, AFAIK [branch] and [merge] still hold for all version control systems.

Comment: I don't think any of `branch`, `merge` or `branching-and-merging` are really necessary, if the correct VCS tag is applied.

Comment: Also `git-branch` and `git-merge` are *commands*, with their own (often misapplied) tags, they aren't equivalent to the generic concept `branch` and `merge`.

Comment: @meagar I agree. That's why I suggested "branch" and "merge" instead.